# Does the IP address of a mobile device change as it connects to different cell towers?

Tags: ip-address

Does the IP address change as a phone moves area and connects to different cell towers?

Comment: This question doesn't fit [so].

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices and cell towers communicate with each other with Global System for Mobile Communications (GSM - see [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM)), which does not provide internet protocol, and thus not an internet protocol (IP) address.

So  the best would be to ask your cell provider that question. However, see https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11738/how-does-the-3g-network-assign-ip-to-smartphones